# Как узнать, в зоне видимости экрана компонент или нет ( в react )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как узнать, в зоне видимости экрана компонент или нет

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать данное решение: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer

Если же не принципиально, то существует нативное API. Почитать про него можешь тут:https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API